# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called in old project, but called in new project which had the same bundle ID with old project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am sure that all the configurations has no problem ,including Provisioning Profile and code, background mode and so on.It's weird that the old project could not called 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' but the new project is called.two project has the same bundle ID, code and other configuration.

I am sure apple side has no problem because other's app can work normal and my new project do.so i suspect that the reason is that the old project did some configuration but i don't know.

the old project was made by `Xcode5`. 
the new project was made by `Xcode7.3`.

could anyone tell me how to solve this problem? thanks a lot.

Here is my code in the `AppDelegate` (the iOS version is 8.0) :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.doubleValue >= 8.0) {

        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings]

    }else{

        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

    NSLog(@"deviceToken ==== %@", deviceToken);  // not called

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"did Fail To Register For Remote Notifications With Error: %@", error); // not called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I went through same problem.

Go to Project target settings and enable Push notification services from 'Capabilities' tab.

It will work.